# How can I dispose/release a string file in this case?

Tags: c#

Im trying to use using but getting error on the using it self.

```
public void Save(string path , bool Locked , PictureBox pb)
        {
            string fn;
            string t = Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(wo_name);
            if (File.Exists(path + "\\" + "DATABASE" + "\\" + t + "\\" + wo_name))
            {
                using  (string f = Path.Combine(path + "\\" + "DATABASE" + "\\" + t + "\\" + wo_name))
                {
                    File.Delete(f);
                }


                fn = path + "\\" + "DATABASE" + "\\" + t + "\\" + wo_name;
            }
            else
            {
                fn = path + "\\" + "DATABASE" + "\\" + wo_name + "\\" + wo_name + ".txt";
            }
            OptionsFile setting_file = new OptionsFile(fn);
            setting_file.SetKey("File Name", fn);
            setting_file.SetKey("Version", version);
            setting_file.SetKey("Button Lock", Locked.ToString());

            setting_file.SetKey("picturebox.Width", pb.Width.ToString());
            setting_file.SetKey("picturebox.Height", pb.Height.ToString());
                setting_file.SetListFloatKey("Coordinates_X", woc.Point_X);
                setting_file.SetListFloatKey("Coordinates_Y", woc.Point_Y);

                setting_file.SetListIntKey("ConnectionStart", connectionStart);
                setting_file.SetListIntKey("ConnectionEnd", connectionEnd);


        }
```

In this save function above i did:

```
using  (string f = Path.Combine(path + "\\" + "DATABASE" + "\\" + t + "\\" + wo_name))
                    {
                        File.Delete(f);
                    }
```

Before it there was just string f = ....Path.... and the Fiel.Delete
I just added the using but on the using im getting error: 'string': type used in a using statement must be implicitly convertible to 'System.IDisposable'

Comment: It doesn't make sense to dispose a string, a string just consumes memory.  Which is already taken care of by the garbage collector.  Do not use *using* here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is there a `Close` or `Dispose` method on the `OptionsFile` class?  Before you exit the `Save` and `Load` functions you should make sure to call one or the other.  If you don't, then you'll likely have to wait until the `setting_file` instance is garbage collected before the lock on the file is released.  If you don't allocate a lot of memory, that could take awhile!

If `OptionsFile.Dispose` exists then enclose your use of `OptionsFile` in a `using` statement, which will call `Dispose` automatically for you at the end of the statement, even if an exception is thrown.

```
    public void Save(string path , bool Locked , PictureBox pb) 
    { 
        string fn; 
        string t = Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(wo_name); 
        if (File.Exists(path + "\\" + "DATABASE" + "\\" + t + "\\" + wo_name)) 
        { 
            string f = Path.Combine(path + "\\" + "DATABASE" + "\\" + t + "\\" + wo_name); 
            File.Delete(f); 

            fn = path + "\\" + "DATABASE" + "\\" + t + "\\" + wo_name; 
        } 
        else 
        { 
            fn = path + "\\" + "DATABASE" + "\\" + wo_name + "\\" + wo_name + ".txt"; 
        } 

        using (OptionsFile setting_file = new OptionsFile(fn))
        {
            setting_file.SetKey("File Name", fn); 
            setting_file.SetKey("Version", version); 
            setting_file.SetKey("Button Lock", Locked.ToString()); 

            setting_file.SetKey("picturebox.Width", pb.Width.ToString()); 
            setting_file.SetKey("picturebox.Height", pb.Height.ToString()); 
            setting_file.SetListFloatKey("Coordinates_X", woc.Point_X); 
            setting_file.SetListFloatKey("Coordinates_Y", woc.Point_Y); 

            setting_file.SetListIntKey("ConnectionStart", connectionStart); 
            setting_file.SetListIntKey("ConnectionEnd", connectionEnd); 
        }
    } 

    public void Load( string path) 
    { 
        string fn = path + "\\" + wo_name;  
        using (OptionsFile setting_file = new OptionsFile(fn))
        {
            woc.Point_X = new List<float>(); 
            woc.Point_Y = new List<float>(); 

            woc.Point_X = setting_file.GetListFloatKey("Coordinates_X"); 
            woc.Point_Y = setting_file.GetListFloatKey("Coordinates_Y"); 


            connectionStart = new List<int>(); 
            connectionEnd = new List<int>(); 

            connectionStart = setting_file.GetListIntKey("ConnectionStart"); 
            connectionEnd = setting_file.GetListIntKey("ConnectionEnd"); 

            lockObject = setting_file.GetKey("Button Lock"); 
        }
    }
```

If `OptionsFile.Close` exists then enclose your use of `OptionsFile` in a `try/finally` block, so you can ensure `Close` is called even if an exception is thrown.

```
    public void Save(string path , bool Locked , PictureBox pb) 
    { 
        string fn; 
        string t = Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(wo_name); 
        if (File.Exists(path + "\\" + "DATABASE" + "\\" + t + "\\" + wo_name)) 
        { 
            string f = Path.Combine(path + "\\" + "DATABASE" + "\\" + t + "\\" + wo_name); 
            File.Delete(f); 

            fn = path + "\\" + "DATABASE" + "\\" + t + "\\" + wo_name; 
        } 
        else 
        { 
            fn = path + "\\" + "DATABASE" + "\\" + wo_name + "\\" + wo_name + ".txt"; 
        } 

        OptionsFile setting_file = null;
        try
        {
            setting_file = new OptionsFile(fn);

            setting_file.SetKey("File Name", fn); 
            setting_file.SetKey("Version", version); 
            setting_file.SetKey("Button Lock", Locked.ToString()); 

            setting_file.SetKey("picturebox.Width", pb.Width.ToString()); 
            setting_file.SetKey("picturebox.Height", pb.Height.ToString()); 
            setting_file.SetListFloatKey("Coordinates_X", woc.Point_X); 
            setting_file.SetListFloatKey("Coordinates_Y", woc.Point_Y); 

            setting_file.SetListIntKey("ConnectionStart", connectionStart); 
            setting_file.SetListIntKey("ConnectionEnd", connectionEnd); 
        }
        finally
        {
            if (setting_file != null)
                setting_file.Close();
        }
    } 

    public void Load( string path) 
    { 
        string fn = path + "\\" + wo_name;  

        OptionsFile setting_file = null;
        try
        {
            setting_file = new OptionsFile(fn);

            woc.Point_X = new List<float>(); 
            woc.Point_Y = new List<float>(); 

            woc.Point_X = setting_file.GetListFloatKey("Coordinates_X"); 
            woc.Point_Y = setting_file.GetListFloatKey("Coordinates_Y"); 


            connectionStart = new List<int>(); 
            connectionEnd = new List<int>(); 

            connectionStart = setting_file.GetListIntKey("ConnectionStart"); 
            connectionEnd = setting_file.GetListIntKey("ConnectionEnd"); 

            lockObject = setting_file.GetKey("Button Lock"); 
        }
        finally
        {
            if (setting_file != null)
                setting_file.Close();
        }
    }
```

If you don't have a `Dispose` or a `Close` method, then you need to modify your `OptionsFile` class to implement `IDisposable` or have a `Close` method, where you in turn close or dispose of any `Stream` based instances.

Comment: Can you show me how to do it in the OptionsFile class ? Edited it to my question.

Comment: @user1526380 Thanks for posting the `OptionsFile` class. After looking at the code of `OptionsFile`, it looks like there isn't need for a `Close` or `Dispose` method, as the class peforms all of its I/O in the two methods `GetKey` and `SetKey`, where it looks as if the streams are being properly closed (if no exceptions are being thrown).

As an aside, you should probably use the `using` statement to wrap the use of the streams.

Comment: Monroe Thomas im trying to use using but getting error on the using im updating my question again to show you how im trying to use the using for example in the Save function.

Comment: @user1526380 No, you can't use a `using` statement around a string.  `using` statements can only be used with instances that implement the `IDisposable` interface, which are the `StreamReader` and `StreamWriter` objects in the `OptionsFile` class.